# Who are the "Men from far away" mentioned in Zechariah 6:15?

Tags: navi-prophets, zecharia-book-of

> וּרְחוֹקִ֣ים ׀ יָבֹ֗אוּ וּבָנוּ֙ בְּהֵיכַ֣ל יְהוָ֔ה וִידַעְתֶּ֕ם כִּֽי־יְהוָ֥ה צְבָא֖וֹת שְׁלָחַ֣נִי אֲלֵיכֶ֑ם וְהָיָה֙ אִם־שָׁמ֣וֹעַ תִּשְׁמְע֔וּן בְּק֖וֹל יְהוָ֥ה אֱלֹהֵיכֶֽם׃ (ס)
>
> Men from far away shall come and take part in the building of the Temple of the LORD, and you shall know that I have been sent to you by the LORD of Hosts—if only you will obey the LORD your God!

([Zechariah 6:15](https://www.sefaria.org/Zechariah.6.15?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en))

Who are the "men from far away" mentioned in this verse ?

Answer (score 3):

The commentary Radak offers two explanations:

> ורחוקים. מגויי הארצות יבואו מארץ רחוקה לבנות בהיכל ה' כלומר להתנדב לבנין הבית ואפשר שהיה זה בימי הורדוס בבנין הגדול שבנה בבית המקדש וי"מ ורחוקים על ישראל המפוזרים בגלות בארץ רחוקה:

1. Non-Jews from distant lands will donate to the construction of the Temple. This could have happened in the time of King Herod who restored the Second Temple although he was not Jewish.
2. It refers to Jews who will return from far away in exile.

The other [commentaries](https://www.sefaria.org/Zechariah.6.15?lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=en) to the verse (Ibn Ezra, Abarbanel, Metzudos, and Malbim) all go with the second explanation.